# DeepCopy for arrays

Tags: c#, .net

Anyone knows if there is an easy or known way to write a deep copy method that's gonna work on arrays of any kind, ie jagged, multidimensional, etc? I plan to write it as an extension method.

There isn't a default method in the framework to do this, right? I am surprised not to find one.

I have seen some serialization-based implementation and they were slow as hell, so I would like a solution which does not use any type of serialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current status of this question is a bit unclear; it was *possibly* a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389) (noted in a deleted reply), but the comments suggest that this isn't quite suitable.

Re serialization slowing things down - well, unfortunately, there is no properly supported "deep clone" functionality in .NET. There is `ICloneable`, but that is a: rarely used, and b: not stated as either shallow or deep. As such, the only remaining **reliable** way to deep clone data is to use serialization.

Re "slow as hell", can you quantify that? Which serialization mechanism was that using? (`BinaryFormatter`? `XmlSerializer`?). For info, you might be interested in [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), which is a pretty fast and efficient alternative binary serializer (and which offers a very handy `T DeepClone<T>(T)` method) - however, it only works with classes that are marked in specific ways (for example, it can use either `[DataContract]` markers, or the bespoke `[ProtoContract]` markers). It is [quicker](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) than the inbuilt serializers, though.

The only other viable option is to write you own, per-type, deep copy routine, and perhaps pass that in (as a `Func<T,T>` or `Converter<T,T>` delegate) to your extension method.

If you only want a **shallow** copy, things are easier, as you can use reflection etc. [Here's an option](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/d9722a51b04300a/0edae91abc1c0f1a#0edae91abc1c0f1a) that creates a shallow copy using a compiled `Expression` (.NET 3.5) for improved performance.

Comment: Thanks Marc. The one I have used was this [one][1]. But it was very slow, it's used in a renderer, so the whole process slowed down by 3-4 times.

Do you know if the .NET team is gonna implement a special method for this?


  [1]: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/8063/deep-clone-an-object-in-net/

Comment: Btw how you add links to comments properly?

Answer (score -1):

I would first take a shot at this:

```
internal static class Prototype
{
  public static T DeepCopy<T>(this IPrototype<T> target)
  {
    T copy;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      formatter.Serialize(stream, (T)target);
      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      copy = (T) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
      stream.Close();
    }
    return copy;
  }
}
```

If this isn't as fast as you want, *then* I'd optimize.

Comment: Yes, this is the code I used from the link I posted to Marc as a comment. It's very slow for my purposes. I need a reliable fast way to do it, but I guess I am doomed since .NET team didn't provide a special method.